# Can NGINX choose proxy_pass backend based on IP?

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I have a situation where we have multiple test environments. Each environment needs to access different versions of a service and we have an `NGINX` proxy that sits in-front of these different services. Currently we're using multiple servers to do the proxy. Is there a way I can use `NGINX` `allow` or `deny` to filter which backend the environments connect to based on remote `IP`?

The `v1` environment has `IP` addresses in the `10.0.1.0/24` range, and `v2` is only connected to by IP's in `10.0.2.0/24`.

#### Current Config

Simplified for brevity.

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name service.v1.net;
  proxy_pass http://10.0.10.56:8081;
}
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name service.v2.net;
  proxy_pass http://10.0.10.56:8082;
}
```

#### What I've tried

Clearly this doesn't work.

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name service.net;

  location / {
    # v1 proxy
    allow 10.0.1.0/24;
    deny all;
    proxy_pass http://10.0.10.56:8081;
  }

  location / {
    # v2 proxy
    allow 10.0.2.0/24;
    deny all;
    proxy_pass http://10.0.10.56:8082;
  }

}
```

#### Also Note...

I know this can be done with serving a proxy on different ports and `iptables` rules - I'm trying to figure out if `NGINX` can do this by itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [ngx_http_geo_module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_geo_module.html) for that. (Which should just work out of the box). It sets variables depending on the client IP address, which can then be used in an if.

```
geo $environment {
  10.0.1.0/24 v1;
  10.0.2.0/24 v2;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name service.net;

  location / {
    if ($environment = v1) {
      proxy_pass http://10.0.10.56:8081;
    }

    if ($environment = v2) {
      proxy_pass http://10.0.10.56:8082;
    }
  }
}
```

All other IPs will see a 404 in this case.

Although this works, be advised that using if within a location block can be very tricky: http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil

Comment: Wow - I'm really surprised this works. Thanks for the pointing out the quirks.